# What vulnerability issues can occur using CakePHP's Json Data Type?

Tags: json, rest, cakephp-3.0

[This page](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#saving-complex-types) states, that:

> When using complex types it is important to validate that the data you are receiving from the end user is the correct type. Failing to correctly handle complex data could result in malicious users being able to store data they would not normally be able to.

What bad could actually happen (knowing, that CakePHP performs its standard security checks in the background) when accepting JSON data from the frontend?

**Which additional security should be added by a CakePHP developer when processing JSON input *for single columns* and relying on the above introduced support for JSON column type?**

Comment: There could be a lot of things. An example: I have my posts and I can edit them. If I can edit via AJAX and the postID is in the JSON you should check on server side if I have right to edit that post, as a malicious user can edit all data what will be sent.

Comment: Well, I think it is all about single columns, not the whole db rows.

Comment: REST isn't about mapping DB records anyway. Imagine you can update a resource state via `PUT`, which has the semantics of replacing the existing content with the new content provided within the request - if a RESTful service allows to update a user resource and the resource of a certain user contains a role definition like `"role": "user"` a user might grant himself `"role": "admin" ` priviledges.  To prevent this, you should validate the incoming request beforehand (`PUT` therefore allows to ignore certain input-data) - this is hower common to all web-input scenarios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mostly it is a concern of having the right structure and coherent data.

For example if you stored serialized data coming from the user and you expect it to be a list of integers like this one:

```
[1, 4, 5, 6]
```

So you can do `array_sum($values)` in any part of your application. It might be possible for someone to submit an array looking like this

```
[{a: 2}, {s: 15}, {}, 'hello']
```

In which case calling `array_sum()` will give you warnings.

It is important to validate the information you are receiving according to the expectations you have about it in terms of structure and data types.